# How can I do to hide a button for 5 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How can I do so that a button is disabled or hidden while there are instructions appearing in my game? I want the button being hidden for 5 seconds but it appears Value of type '(UIButton) -> ()' has no member 'isHidden'

```
btn.isHidden = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now(), +5){
            btn.isHidden =false
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax errors:

1. You don´t need the `,` after `now()
2. You need to have space before and after `+`
3. You need to have space before and after `=`
4. Inside the `DispatchQueue` you need to use `self` for your properties

Final code:

```
btn.isHidden = true
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
    self.btn.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which line is giving that error?

is it in closure?

```
btn.isHidden = true
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
  self.btn.isHidden =false
}
```

Comment: No `[weak self]`, please, GCD does **not** cause retain cycles, just `self.btn...`